# Escaping spaces in string variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Have a script that gets the current path and grabs the last two directories in that path

```
for /F "tokens=5,6 delims=\" %%a in ("%0") do (
    ECHO %%a
    ECHO %%b
)
```

output is:

```
2017
Customer 91 Folder
```

I need the output to look like:

```
2017
Customer\ 91\ Folder
```

I am using this variable to envoke and rsync script in linux which needs the directory path spaces escaped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=5,6 delims=\" %%a in ("%0") do (
    ECHO %%a
    set "second_line=%%b"
    ECHO !second_line: =\ !
)
```

Comment: Um, I'd suggest `!second_line: =\ !`...doesn't work with metavariables!